# Azure SignalR Service with native Android app?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core-signalr

Is there a way to connect native Android app to Azure SignalR Service with curent java client in ASP.NET Core 2.2 Preview 3? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: We do test the client on Android, and it should work. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Also, the docs are being updated for Preview 3. See https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/pull/9112

Comment: Well I got this issue first (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/3141). But I created new project with min api 26 trying to connect to Azure SignalR Service. So basically my problem is that I dont know what to pass in withAccessTokenProvider (). Sure, I know it is Single<String>, but is it ok if I pass a retrofit method that calls rest api for acquiring jwt token, and return it as Single. Or I should acquire token at different time and place, and than pass it as a Single<String> from memory? There is no documentation for that.

Comment: Yeah, the docs are early right now, I've filed https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/9171 to track this change, feel free to comment on the docs directly or file issues on that repo if you have docs questions!The general pattern is to pass `Single.defer(() -> { /* some code to fetch your access token */` as the `accessTokenFactory`. You return a `Single<String>` from the lambda provided to `.defer` which means you can chain asynchronous actions. So yeah, there's no problem with calling the REST API directly within the factory.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was helpfull.

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse

Is passing an empty string (for if the http has an error) is fine?

I'm having an issue where sometimes on the Android side, after a short disconnect the hub seems to be connected again, but on the backend, it won't show up....